# How can i run my react native app on Genny motion emulator?

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

i tried to run my react native app on genny motion 
through "react-native run-android"   but it continuously give me this error , i also setup Android)_Home in system variable and also connect gennymotion with android studio but still receive an error  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCGVL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a permissions error, it should work when you change the security settings of your project folder (if that doesn't work - then your build folder)

Navigate to your root folder (manage_my_rides_mobile-develop). Right click on it > Properties > Security > Edit - check all.

If that doesn't work

Go to `manage_my_rides_mobile-develop/android/build` > Repeat as above.

If that doesn't work

Go to the directory which is failing, and delete manually.